# Optimizing code for better performance and quality

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have this calculation method that calculates 6 fields and total.
It works.
Question is how can I optimize it performance wise and code quality wise.
Just want to get some suggestions on how to write better code.

```py
def _ocnhange_date(self):
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    self.date = date
    self.drawer_potential = self.drawer_id.product_categ_price * self.drawer_qty
    self.flexible_potential = self.flexible_id.product_categ_price * self.flexible_qty
    self.runner_potential = self.runner_id.product_categ_price * self.runner_qty
    self.group_1_potential = self.group_1_id.product_categ_price * self.group_1_qty
    self.group_2_potential = self.group_2_id.product_categ_price * self.group_2_qty
    self.group_3_potential = self.group_3_id.product_categ_price * self.group_3_qty
    total = [self.drawer_potential,self.flexible_potential,self.runner_potential,self.group_1_potential,
             self.group_2_potential,self.group_3_potential]
    self.total_potentail = sum(total)
```

Comment: Which version of odoo are you using?

Comment: i'm using odoo 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see two things you can improve here:

1. Use Odoo's `Datetime` class to get "now" because it already takes Odoo's datetime format into consideration. In the end that's more maintainable, because if Odoo decides to change the whole format system wide, you have to change your method, too.
2. Try to avoid so many assignments and instead use methods which allow a combined update of some values. For onchange methods this would be `update()` and for other value changes it's obviously `write()`.

```py
def _onchange_date(self):
    self.update({
        'date': fields.Datetime.now(),
        'drawer_potential': self.drawer_id.product_categ_price * self.drawer_qty,
        'flexible_potential': self.flexible_id.product_categ_price * self.flexible_qty,
        # and so on
    })
```

Comment: Although it's true what you say about maintainability, in the lower level, your code will perform exactly the same. There's a difference when using write, but with update (needed for an onchange indeed) it's just the same.

Comment: Yes i know, update is not working like write. But now he has to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: you should worry about performance mostly on batch operations. Your case is an onchange method, which means:

- it will be triggered manually by user interaction.
- it will only affect a single record at a time.
- it will not perform database writes.

So, basically, this one will not be a critical bottleneck in your module.

However, you're asking how that could get better, so here it goes. It's just an idea, in some points just different (not better), but this way you can maybe see a different approach in some place that you prefer:

```
def _ocnhange_date(self):
    # Use this alternative method, easier to maintain
    self.date = fields.Datetime.now()
    # Less code here, although almost equal
    # performance (possibly less)
    total = 0
    for field in ("drawer", "flexible", "runner",
                  "group_1", "group_2", "group_3"):
        potential = self["%s_id"].product_categ_price * self["%s_qty"]
        total += potential
        self["%s_potential"] = potential
    # We use a generator instead of a list
    self.total_potential = total
```